# Python HTTP Get Request (Occasional 401 - Unauthorized)

Tags: python, http, get

I'm using the following python script to connect with adsl modem and retrive wifi information

```
host = 192.168.1.1
pwd = **********

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)
auth = b64encode("admin:"+pwd).decode("ascii")
head = { 'Authorization' : 'Basic %s' %  auth }
conn.request("GET", "/basic/home_wlan.htm", headers = head)
resp = conn.getresponse()

#Do something ....

conn.close()
```

Most of the times evereything is OK, but sometimes happemes to receive `401 - Unauthorized` http error.
When I retry executing immidiatly after this error, everything works ok. Now, to overcome this I added the following code immidiatly before `#Do something...`:

```
if resp.status == 401:
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)
    auth = b64encode("admin:"+pwd).decode("ascii")
    head = { 'Authorization' : 'Basic %s' %  auth }
    conn.request("GET", "/basic/home_wlan.htm", headers = head)
    resp = conn.getresponse()
```

In other terms I'm repeating the connection negotiation if 401 occurs. In my opinion this is not so elegant to do this. **Can someone give me a more acceptable solution?**

Comment: Mostly looks like your router's fault. You can make it a function, and recall the function if needed.

Comment: Don't you mean `if rep == 401:`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AntoinePelisse I think this is best since then you can call it over and over again.

Comment: Right, let me fix `resp==404` to `resp==401`

Comment: @antoine-pelisse @jakekimds  If my modem is the problem, I'm very glad to accept this ugly solution. Maybe I'll add a `while` that retries some times with a given interval. The question remains: Am I sure that the modem is problem? Maybe I'll try some other web page with basic authentication to test the code.